# Массив с данными на JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

Имеется `span`, класс которого соответствует классу скрытого div-a, содержащего в себе картинку.

При клике на `span` соответствующий `div` появляется.

Скрипт выглядит следующим образом:

```
<script>
  $( "span.123" ).click(function() {
      $( "div.123" ).fadeToggle(function()      {   
      });
  }); 
</script>
```

А если быть точнее, то в коде вместо **123** стоит `php` код, выводящий нужное значение:

```
<?php the_field('number_1'); ?>
```

Т.е. целиком весь код выглядит следующим образом:

```
<script>
$( "span.<?php the_field('number_1'); ?>" ).click(function() {
    $( "div.<?php the_field('number_1'); ?>" ).fadeToggle(function() {

    });
});
</script>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `span.<?php the_field('number_1'); ?>` и `div.<?php the_field('number_1'); ?>` может быть до 30 штук.

Значение класса при этом может содержать как цифры так и латинские буквенные символы.

финальный `html` выглядит так:

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <span class="random_nubmer_1"></span> 
    <span class="random_nubmer_2></span> 
    <span class=" random_nubmer_3></span>
    <!--И так далее...-->
</div>
<div id="wrapper_2">
    <div class="random_nubmer_1"></div>
    <div class="random_nubmer_2></div> 
    <div class=" random_nubmer_3></div> 
    И так далее... 
</div>
```

При клике на `<span class="random_nubmer_1"></span>` отображается `<div class="random_nubmer_1"></div>`, а остальные скрываются.

**Вопрос**: как объединить все 30 штук в один код?

Прилагаю схематичный пример того что хочу получить:
[image]

Если можно поясните, пожалуйста, с комментариями.

Comment: вопрос: каждый div помещен в свой span? или как выглядит итоговый html? и для чего эти классы нужны? они содержат свои индивидуальные параметры в css? или просто для вывода числа в див?

Comment: Нет, div от  span существуют независимо друг от друга. Класс нужен чтобы индентифицировать блок, можно место класса поставить для div  id.  В целом - это похоже на то, как на странице интернет-магазина переключаются цвета товара.

Comment: Можете, все-таки, в вопрос добавить финальную html? Как она выглядит

Comment: Разметка выглядит следующим образом:
`<div id="wrapper">
     <span class="random_nubmer_1"></span>
     <span class="random_nubmer_2></span>
     <span class="random_nubmer_3></span>
     <!--И так далее...-->
</div>
<div id="wrapper_2">
     <div class="random_nubmer_1"></div>
     <div class="random_nubmer_2></div>
     <div class="random_nubmer_3></div>
      И так далее...
</div>`

При клике на `<span class="random_nubmer_1"></span>`
Отображается `<div class="random_nubmer_1"></div>` а остальные скрываются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле вам не нужно присваивать никаких классов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.к. у вас уже идет соответствие элементов, то получается, что первый спан в блоке `wrapper` соответствует первому `div` в блоке `wrapper_2`, второй - второму, третий - третьему и т.д.

На основе этого и делаем логику:

- Определяем индекс span'а, на котором был произведен клик
- Скрываем все `div` в блоке `wrapper_2`
- Показываем `div` с тем же индексом, что и у `span` на который кликнули
- Всё

```js
$('#wrapper').on('click', 'span', function(){
    var elIndex = $(this).index();
    $('#wrapper_2 div').hide();  
    $('#wrapper_2 div').eq( elIndex ).fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;       
}

#wrapper_2 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#wrapper_2 div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <span class="random_nubmer_1">span1</span> 
    <span class="random_nubmer_2">span2</span> 
    <span class="random_nubmer_3">span3</span>
    <!--И так далее...-->
</div>
<div id="wrapper_2">
    <div class="random_nubmer_1">div11</div>
    <div class="random_nubmer_2">div22</div> 
    <div class="random_nubmer_3">div33</div> 
    <!--И так далее...-->
</div>
```

Comment: мог второй раз `$('#wrapper_2 div')` не писать :) у тебя ж все на одном наборе происходит

Comment: @Grundy так нагляднее просто, как мне кажется, как раз соответствуют пунктам, которые я перечислил